# Is there an USB dongle, which allows you to receive SMS on Windows 10 PC without SIM slot?

Tags: windows-10, sms, sim-card, lte, 4g

I have Dell XPS15 7590 which does not have a SIM card slot. Previously I had HP zBook 15 which had this feature. I used the SIM to receive SMS and when I was on a trip I used it as 4G modem to connect to the internet. **Receiving SMS is crucial feature to me.**

I'm wondering whether there is any USB adapter which add this feature also to PCs which does not have SIM card slot.

I've tried 4G LTE USB modem, but it was able only to connect me to the internet.

Many thanks for any comments on this.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that  **Huawei E3372 LTE USB** stick does support SMS functionality.

It's not integrated to the Windows Messaging because it's configured to so called HiLink mode. It *should* be possible by flashing the modem to stick mode - I found a tutorial, but I haven't tried it yet:  [Flashing a Huawei E3372h 4G LTE stick from Hilink to Stick mode – 0xf8.org](https://www.0xf8.org/2017/01/flashing-a-huawei-e3372h-4g-lte-stick-from-hilink-to-stick-mode/)

---

[image: Huawei E3372 LTE USB SMS].